# Failing to verify ECDSA signature

Tags: go, verify, ecdsa

I have a signature:

> 3044022014d647cd08f1ea5b31d1e6539b6cbceb9182f6e7b2e29fb969354ef7e3434923022028bb4eda36af410149baa936322e7c0e46cc5540a3aa89c811bc3c360028bfd301

a hash

> f27c6c3aa42563c958292922be1e53fe107f4db0dfadba11122f0b12bf77f3ab

and a pubkey

> 04b0bd634234abbb1ba1e986e884185c61cf43e001f9137f23c2c409273eb16e6537a576782eba668a7ef8bd3b3cfb1edb7117ab65129b8a2e681f3c1e0908ef7b

Below is my Go code to verify the signature but it fails! I have information that the three pieces should validate OK and some other person has verified them in other ways. So I want to kown what mistake in this Go code make me get the false result.

if you want more information，this link is about how i build my signature and how someone say he success verify in other ways. I feel helpless now:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=4879014.msg43992837#msg43992837

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/elliptic"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    pubkey, err := hex.DecodeString("b0bd634234abbb1ba1e986e884185c61cf43e001f9137f23c2c409273eb16e6537a576782eba668a7ef8bd3b3cfb1edb7117ab65129b8a2e681f3c1e0908ef7b")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    curve := elliptic.P256()
    // length
    keyLen := len(pubkey)

    x := big.Int{}
    y := big.Int{}
    x.SetBytes(pubkey[:(keyLen / 2)])
    y.SetBytes(pubkey[(keyLen / 2):])

    rawPubKey := ecdsa.PublicKey{curve, &x, &y}

    // hash
    hash, err := hex.DecodeString("f27c6c3aa42563c958292922be1e53fe107f4db0dfadba11122f0b12bf77f3ab")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    r := big.Int{}
    s := big.Int{}
    rr, err := hex.DecodeString("14d647cd08f1ea5b31d1e6539b6cbceb9182f6e7b2e29fb969354ef7e3434923")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    ss, err := hex.DecodeString("28bb4eda36af410149baa936322e7c0e46cc5540a3aa89c811bc3c360028bfd3")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    r.SetBytes(rr)
    s.SetBytes(ss)

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", ecdsa.Verify(&rawPubKey, hash[:], &r, &s))    
}
```

Comment: Verification still fails after fixing the space. The code seems fine, have you verified yourself that this is a valid signature using other tools?

Comment: very thinks your reply.this link is about how i build my signature and how someone say he success verify in other ways. I feel helpless now.             [https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=4879014.msg43992837#msg43992837]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the wrong curve. P-256, also known as secp256r1, is *not* the same as the curve used in Bitcoin, which is secp256k1. Your public key doesn’t correspond to a point on P-256 (you can check with `curve.IsOnCurve(&x, &y)`), but it *is* a point on secp256k1.

Golang doesn’t include support for the Bitcoin curve, so you will need to find a library that does ECDSA using it.

I can confirm that signature does verify that data for that key if you use the correct curve.

Comment: very thinks!! you are master in bitcoin and go!

Comment: i have a go code complement it ! now i also have a problem about the op_checksig,can you help me?

Comment: this is my new question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52073613/failing-to-verify-ecdsa-sinature-2

Comment: You may find a secp256k1 library suitable for Bitcoin at https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd/btcec